# How do I get lit textured materials in Multitexture BGE?

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine, interface

As the title says, how can I get Materials that contain textures to work and not be shadeless in BGE that is set to Multitexture mode? I cannot use GLSL.

I need to use materials so I can control the specularity of my objects. If I set the Blend mode for my textures to Mix the object becomes shadeless, if I set it to multiply the object becomes black.

Here are some pics to demonstrate my predicament...

Normal viewport:
[image: Normal viewport image]

BGE running, texture set to mix:
[image: BGE Pic 1]

BGE running, texture set to multiply:
[image: BGE Pic 2]

BGE running, no material assigned (using UV image texture):
[image: BGE Pic 3]

Comment: It seems you are in 'Shaded able

Answer (score 2):

1. Unwrap the UV texture
2. Add a material
3. Check "Face Textures" under Options in the materials panel.

You may now adjust the spec.  Make sure the textures panel is empty.

Comment: I could have searched my whole life before knowing the texture stack has to be empty....Thanks. Also is it possible to use normal maps in Multitexture mode ?